IntelliJ GUI Designer does not compile the layout into bytecode
I am creating a proof of concept using swing and the gui designer.
As of now I have a TittleScreen.java and a TittleScreen.form files.
The designer is set to generate binary class files, but when I build the project the class fields are not set up and therefore raise a NullPointerException when trying to be accesed.
I decompiled the generated class file with the built in decompiler of IntelliJ and found out that no code was generated fot the component initialization and layout.
I have tried almost everything, from running fresh builds to checking if the .form file is correctly associated to the .java file.
If it is of any help I am running with gradle. I am mentioning this because I saw on one of the public forums that a user changed from gradle to maven and everything worked.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
